# Not able to see output, when reload the page. Output come just for a sec, then coming map error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Above code outputs basic Netflix movie name and images. Output comes just for a sec, then some error is coming on console related with maps, however it seems fine to be. what is the error here?
I used ReactJS here with useeffect hook, tried it for netflix clone

**Row.js:**

```
function Row({ fetchUrl, title }) {
  const baseURL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/"
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl)
      setMovies(request.data.results)
      return request
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [fetchUrl])

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <h2> {title} </h2>
      {movies.map((movie) => (
        <img src={`${baseURL}${movie.poster_path}`} alt={movie.name} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

**requests.js:**

```js
const API_KEY = "ecfc81ae98ad1c0720b07e83400de828"

const requests = {
  fetchTrending: `/trending/all/week?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`,
  fetchNetflixOriginals: `discover/tv?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_networks=213`
}
```

**axios.js:**

```
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL : "https://api.themoviedb.org/3",
});
```

**app.js:**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div ClassName="App">
      <h1> Hey !! lets build Netflix</h1>
      <Row title="Netflix Originals" fetchUrl={requests.netflixOriginals} />
      <Row title="Trending" fetchUrl={requests.fetchTrending} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Error:**
[image]

Comment: Please add the returned response from API. Without that, we can only speculate. It appears it doesn't contain a `results` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

{movies && movies.map ((movie) => (
<img src={`${baseURL}${movie.poster_path}`} alt={movie.name}/>
))}

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're querying [genres](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/genres/get-movie-list) endpoints, which return the movie list inside `genres`.

If I'm correct, you should replace

```js
setMovies(request.data.results)
```

with

```js
setMovies(request.data.genres)
```

---

Most importantly, `console.log` is your friend:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(fetchUrl).then(r => console.log(r.data))
}, [fetchUrl])
```

Logging the exact data returned will help you figure out where the actual list is (and what you need to assign to `movies`).